# Android : Gradle update from 2.10 to 2.4 failing

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am working on an Android project on Ubuntu Linux, where I have Android Studio IDE. Till today, I had Android-studio-141, but I saw the update and decided to update. It also asked me if I wanted to update to Gradle-2.4 which has `Instant Run`. Given how much time Gradle was consuming for me, instant-run seemed nice. Unfortunately, Gradle-2.4 is not working out.

Whenever I try a gradle build, I get the following error :

```
Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/akshay/Downloads/To backup/ backup/myapp/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

The file mentioned in error log, I went there, and the distribution URL was at 2.4, setting it to 2.1 did solve the problem, but 2.4 is not working. 
**How can I successfully migrate to Gradle 2.4?**

Gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
#Mon Oct 05 11:56:56 CEST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you try to downgrade to 2.4? That's outdated. Use 2.10.

Comment: @Tomik : That's strange, because I was suggested upgrade to 2.40 from 2.10 by IDE post installation... And does Gradle has some reverse numbering scheme? 2.40 is higher than 2.10.

Comment: You are confusing the numbering a bit. Gradle versions are these: 2.1 < 2.4 < 2.10 < 2.11

Comment: @Tomik : Okay, my mistake. Can you tell me which version has Instant-run and how I can upgrade it to that version. EVerytime I am compiling my project, it is taking more than 2 minutes for it to finish and then push, tedious it has become.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Instant Run:

- Update Android Studio to 2.0 or 2.1 from beta channel.
- Use Gradle 2.10 - your `gradle-wrapper.properties` seems ok (the last line says what version do you use).
- Use latest version of Android Gradle plugin - currently 2.1.0-beta3.
- Make sure you enabled Instant run in Android studio (Settings/Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Enable Instant Run).

To set version of Android Gradle plugin, edit toplevel `build.gradle` file. It should contain:

```
buildscript {
    …
    dependencies {
        …
        // versions can be found at
        // https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-beta3'
    }
}
```

Documentation for Instant Run can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/instant-run).